Why numba doesn't calculate after a number of index?
I wrote a simulation on what happens to earth's position if a rogue planet enters solar system, I used numba library for this. However while running the for loop numba library says the vectors are nan after index n/5769, why is that ? I created a new variable called m, which is the last index my for loop could calculate with using function @njit. It would be so much better if the code calculated untill index n. Here's the code:
#For some reason while using numba library, total_time/5769 will give you the maximum index it can calculate. I have no idea why that happens, 
#but if you want, you can multiply total_time and your max. index will be bigger sooooooo
import multiprocessing
import time
import numpy as np
import skyfield
import numba
from skyfield.api import load, Topos
from datetime import timedelta
from numba import njit, prange


start_time = time.perf_counter() #Starts counting time untill code finishes

dt = 72  #Time that acceleration is assumed to be constant, smaller is better

total_time = 86400 * 365.24219 * 8.0125 *10 #Total simulation time.  43829*5770
n = int(total_time/dt) -1
m = int(total_time/5769) #m is the maximum index number that numba can calculate without giving NaN
total_time_till_m = int(total_time*dt/5769)
#By multiplying index and dt, it is possible to find the total_time until index number.
#So the total_time that actually printed in the last is total_time*dt/5769

#Define position-velocity-acceleraiton vectors for objects
vctr_position_earth = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3))
vctr_velocity_earth = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3))
vctr_acceleration_earth = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3))

vctr_position_moon = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3) )
vctr_velocity_moon = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3) )
vctr_acceleration_moon = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3))

vctr_position_Rogue = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3))
vctr_velocity_Rogue = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3))
vctr_acceleration_Rogue = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3))

#Define the net distance between objects 
net_distance_earth = np.zeros((int(total_time/dt)))
net_distance_sun = np.zeros(int(total_time / dt))


#Define the distances of floats to Rogue as norm
norm_distance_earth = np.zeros(int(total_time/dt))


#Beginning position and velocities for floats


vctr_position_earth[0] = np.array([-8.612126415163520E+07 ,-1.243405742161587E+08 , 7.159140121236444E+03])
vctr_velocity_earth[0] = np.array([2.400973596546069E+01, -1.706428457849702E+01, 1.571000011289847E-03])

vctr_position_moon[0] = np.array([-8.755507860116081E+07,-1.247124832815350E+08 ,6.257550822596997E+04])
vctr_velocity_moon[0] = np.array([2.352284152220006E+01 ,-1.790602303115681E+01 ,-6.028641210510699E-02])

vctr_position_Rogue[0] = np.array([-8.943037154218392E+07 ,-1.232424009446662E+08 , 3.215852965261042E+04])
vctr_velocity_Rogue[0] = np.array([1.176261267381250E+01,-3.023110865122838E+01,-4.772431731046794])


#Define constants
G = 0.00000000000000000006674
M_SUN = float(1989000000000000000000000000000)
M_JUPITER = 1898130000000000000000000000
M_earth = float(5972200000000000000000000)
M_MARS = 639000000000000000000000
M_VENUS = 4800000000000000000000000
M_mercury = 328500000000000000000000
M_SATURN = 5683 * 10**23
M_URANUS = 8681 * 10**22
M_NEPTUNE = 10**26
M_Rogue = float(5 * M_JUPITER)
M_Moon = 7.34767309 * 10**22

#Create a list to append distaxnces from floats
net_distance_sun_lst = []
net_distance_earth_lst = []
net_distance_mars_lst = []
net_distance_venus_lst = []
net_distance_jupiter_lst = []
net_distance_saturn_lst = []
net_distance_uranus_lst = []
net_distance_neptune_lst = []
net_distance_mercury_lst = []

#Calculate positions of Rogue and distances from floats for Total Time
@njit(parallel=True)
def compute_position(total_time, dt, G, M_SUN, M_earth, vctr_position_Rogue, vctr_velocity_Rogue, vctr_acceleration_Rogue, vctr_position_earth, vctr_velocity_earth, vctr_acceleration_earth):
    for n in prange(1, int(total_time/dt)):
        vctr_acceleration_Rogue[n] = - G * M_SUN* vctr_position_Rogue[n-1]/(np.linalg.norm(vctr_position_Rogue[n-1])**3) 
        - G * M_earth * (vctr_position_Rogue[n-1]-vctr_position_earth[n-1])/(np.linalg.norm(vctr_position_Rogue[n-1]-vctr_position_earth[n-1]**3)) 

        vctr_velocity_Rogue[n] = vctr_velocity_Rogue[n-1] + vctr_acceleration_Rogue[n-1]*dt
        vctr_position_Rogue[n] = vctr_position_Rogue[n-1] + vctr_velocity_Rogue[n-1]*dt + 0.5*dt**2*vctr_acceleration_Rogue[n-1]

       

        vctr_acceleration_earth[n] = - G * M_SUN * vctr_position_earth[n-1]/np.linalg.norm(vctr_position_earth[n-1])**3
        - G * M_Rogue * (vctr_position_earth[n-1] - vctr_position_Rogue[n-1])/(np.linalg.norm(vctr_position_earth[n-1] - vctr_position_Rogue[n-1])**3)

        vctr_velocity_earth[n] = vctr_velocity_earth[n-1] + vctr_acceleration_earth[n-1]*dt
        vctr_position_earth[n] = vctr_position_earth[n-1] + vctr_velocity_earth[n-1]*dt + 0.5*(dt**2)*vctr_acceleration_earth[n-1]
    
    
        
        

compute_position(total_time, dt, G, M_SUN, M_earth, vctr_position_Rogue, vctr_velocity_Rogue, vctr_acceleration_Rogue, vctr_position_earth, vctr_velocity_earth, vctr_acceleration_earth)







#End time counter
end_time = time.perf_counter()

elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print(f"Elapsed time: (s) {elapsed_time}\n")
print(f"Earth's first position: {vctr_position_earth[0]}")
print(f"Earth's position in index n: {vctr_position_earth[n]}")
print(f"Earth's position in index m: {vctr_position_earth[m]}")
print(f"Earth's last velocity: {vctr_velocity_earth[m]}\n")
print(f"Total time untill m:{total_time_till_m} seconds")
print(f"Total time untill m:{total_time_till_m/86400} days")

#5479

#5759

I tried changing the type of object I used(a.k.a np.zeros and dtype=object) but it didn't work.

You shouldn't be using parallel=True in your @njit decorator here. You need the loop to be carried out sequentially otherwise you can/will get wrong results (see the discussion at https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html#explicit-parallel-loops)

Does it work without numba?

While the computation can be a bit optimised (not sure much with only Numba), you cannot compute that in parallel as pointed out by MattPitkin. Can't you use a bigger dt or find an analytical expression to compute this more efficiently with less steps than 35_118_036? Maybe there is some way to exploit the (quasi-)periodicity of planet movements.

@Tarik yes it does without numba.

@MattPitkin It worked when I deleted Parallel=True statement, thanks a lot!

@JérômeRichard I can use a bigger dt, but in result I'd lose accuracy. It may not be significant for a total time like 1 year, but for 10 years or so dt needs to be less. Thanks for your reply

Ok. By the way, the line starting with - G * M_Rogue * ... does nothing. If this is a continuation of the previous, parenthesis are needed. Otherwise, this part will simply be ignored by Numba (CPython will compute it but it will have no impact on results). Besides, constants like 0.00000000000000000006674 can just be defined as 6.674e-20 which is much sorter and human readable. Moreover, large integers in your simulation are bigger than 64 bit and will overflow unless they are converted in CPython (which seems to be done for the variables used).

Oh and you wrote np.linalg.norm(vctr_position_Rogue[n-1]-vctr_position_earth[n-1]**3) which looks like a mistake compared to other lines. Did you mean np.linalg.norm(vctr_position_Rogue[n-1]-vctr_position_earth[n-1])**3? Note the location of the **3. The first formula would be very weird to me (it does not make sense physically). Note the compilation time is benchmarked and the generated code is inefficient. Also note the the line - G * M_earth * ... also have the same issue than before. Are you sure this computation actually compute something correct?

@JérômeRichard Oh my god thank you. I never realised that it needed to be in a parenthesis, since this first line ( - G * M_Sun*...) worked without parenthesis, I thought none of them needed one. But now it works fine. Thank you!
